# Using Server-Sent Event in cake PHP

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, server-sent-events

I am using Server-Sent Event to send data from core php to html and it is running fine..

I used the example from the reference http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp

But when I am trying to do the same thing in CakePHP using restful apis it is creating issues.

Here's my code:

Controller: `sseController.php`

```
           public function sseTest() {
                header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
                header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

                $time = date('r');
                $this->set('finalData',"data: The server time is: {$time}\n\n");
            }
```

View: `sse_view.ctp`

```
<?php
     echo json_encode($finalData);
     flush();
?>
```

HTML calling api is...

```
    if(typeof(EventSource)!=="undefined")
    {
       var source=new EventSource('http://localhost/b2c/api/reports/sseTest');
       source.onmessage=function(event)
       {
          document.getElementById("result").innerHTML+=event.data + "<br>";
       };
    }
    else
    {
             document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Sorry, your browser does not support   server-sent events...";
    }
```

Please suggest some idea.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to `json_encode` invalid JSON in your view and this could be causing you problems

```
"data: The server time is: {$time}\n\n" // this is not JSON
```

You need to change the view by removing `json_encode` according to the [HTML5 Server-Sent Events docs in w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp)

The view `sse_view.ctp` would look like:

```
<?php
     echo $finalData;
     flush();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED: I have try this on my local and this is working!

Controller: sseController.php

```
public function sse_test() { //change your function to this (cakePHP standards)
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
    $time = date('r');
    $this->set('finalData',"data: The server time is: {$time}\n\n");
}

public function sse_view(){ //add this one

}
```

View: sse_view.ctp

```
<div id="result"></div>
<script tye="text/javascript">
   if(typeof(EventSource)!=="undefined")
   {
         var source=new EventSource('<?php echo "http://localhost{$this->base}/reports/sse_test";?>'); //you  must check this one if the path is correct (modify if not correct or try to alert it)
        // alert('<?php echo "http://localhost{$this->base}/reports/sse_test";?>'); //uncomment to check if your using the correct path
   source.onmessage=function(event)
   {
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML+=event.data + "<br>";
   };
}
else
{
       document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Sorry, your browser does not support   server-sent events...";
}
```

create a file, under the same path of sse_view.ctp: sse_test.ctp

```
<?php
    echo $finalData;
    flush();
?>
```

Comment: Hi zynder, Your code is also not working... i have already tried this one. :(

Comment: Request URL:http://localhost/b2c/api/reports/sseTest
Request Headers CAUTION: Provisional headers are shown.
Accept:text/event-stream
Cache-Control:no-cache
Referer:http://localhost/sse/sse.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36

Answer (score 0):

Change this code to

```
$this->layout = false;
```

in the controller action function

Answer (score 0):

Server Sent events is the way to automatically to send request to server and get response after regular time interval.SSEs are uses HTTP protocol i.e it does not require special server like socket. Best use is get live notification from server. For example if we have social networking site and we need friend request notification or accept notification.

How to use steps :

1. Let suppose we are working in friends controller then in the action `get_friend_request_count`:

   ```
   function get_friend_request_count($user_id) {
       header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
       header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

       //example query
       $friend_count = $this->friend-  >find('count',array('conditions'=>array('user_id'=>$user_id)));
       echo "retry: 5000\n data: Friend count : { $friend_count }\n\n";
       flush();
       die;
   }
   ```
2. Write a javascript code that is available every where or in the layout:

   ```
   if (typeof(EventSource)!=="undefined") {
       var source = new EventSource('localhost/friends/get_friend_request_count'); //modify path as correct path
       source.onmessage = function(event) {
           $('#friend_count').html(event.data);
       };
   }
   else {
       alert('Server sent event does not work with IE')
   }
   ```